# Design for iPhone and iPad when iPad will show all Container Views and iPhone only some of them

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

So using Xcode 6.1.1, I have size classes enabled in Storyboard.

My plan is in iPad sized views I'll have 4 View Controllers visible.  Each one has interconnected data that changes when input is adjusted in another view controller using NSNotifications.
Since it has multiple view controllers I added container views on storyboard.

[image: ipad view]

When the app is loaded in an iPhone, I instead want to use two view controllers

- for entering input (number 4 in image)
- and a master(number 3 in image) with the option to show detail views(number 1 and 2 in image) as modal views

[image: iphone view]

My question is, I understand on the iPad sizing how to get all the view controllers to interact with one another, but in the iPhone view how do I enable navigation so that the user can access the detail views?

Comment: Access navigation through what?

Comment: I guess another navigation controller.  I guess I'm asking how I would design this in storyboard so that when a button on view 3 is pushed it modally presents view 1 or 2

Comment: I think size classes allow you to add and remove certain views for different resolutions. Can you do the same with segues?

Comment: Brilliant idea, but unfortunately I don't see the option to add/remove segues for different size classes.  I can remove the button that accesses the detail view when in the iPad view so that may solve that issue. I see the show, show detail, present modally and present as popover as the new segue. I want to cover the whole screen I'm assuming I should use present modally.  Also previously I had a navigation controller between the button and the modal view so that that the navigation bar(and associated back button) was present.  Will adding the same navigation controller affect the iPad view?

Comment: No it's not an option, when you switch size class for storyboard, you can drop new button for example that will only show up in that particular size class. See tutorial https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng rewind to 7:55

Comment: You should use modal presentation then, instead of back button you'll have close button then. This is very standard approach when porting app too smaller devices.